# Xlabel/Ylabel Position for Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

The Tikz code below generates the following picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

 \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=100,ybar,bar width=2.8mm,ylabel={\textcolor{forestgreen}{\textbf{Number of Policies}}},yticklabel=$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$,
 xticklabel=$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$,xlabel={Score Based on Expected Loss Ratio}]
  \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:100,fill=forestgreen] {1/10000*(2.5*(100-x)^6.2*exp(-(100-x)/5.7)*(0.8+0.2*rnd)+10000*x)};
 \end{axis}

 \begin{axis}[ymin=0,axis y line=right,ylabel={\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Actual Loss Ratio (\%)}}},xtick=\empty,ymax=200,ymin=0,
 yticklabel=$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$]
  \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:100,thick,blue] {1.02*(180-1.5*x+20*(rnd-0.5))};
 \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Overall, I think it looks decent but the labels (particularly # of policies and 'score based on...') look too close to the axis labels. **My question is I want a little more spacing so the labels are a bit further out. Is that possible?**

Comment: Just add `ylabel style={yshift=1em}` to the first axis and `ylabel style={yshift=-1em}` to the second axis, or some other distance instead of `1em`. Note that in order to reproduce your problem, users typically expect you to provide an example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. In this case this is particularly important because when I wrap your code in the MWE from the answer to your previous question, the labels are not that close. That is, the issue is caused by something you do not disclose here.

Comment: Note also that you can add the text color and the font weight to the above-mentioned `ylabel style`, e.g. `ylabel style={yshift=1em,text=ForestGreen,font=\bfseries}` is arguably easier to deal with.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! I was unaware of the "ylabel style={yshift=1em}" command and that is extremely helpful. I've got the picture working exactly as I want it to look now! You are awesome and I highly appreciate your help :)!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was solved by Marmot in the comments

Comment: @Andrew agreed!